# Not able to send sms from smsgateway.me after its update

Tags: javascript, json, http-post, postman, sms-gateway

I was sending sms programmatically using php from localhost. But today after update of [smsgateway.me](https://smsgateway.me/sms-api-documentation/messages/sending-a-sms-message) to v4, I am not able to send any message. I actually don't know how to pass API key to given example. I tried a lot but no success.

```
Request Endpoint
Endpoint:   https://smsgateway.me/api/v4/message/send
Method: POST
Request Parameters
Name    Location    Required    Description
Content body    true    JSON payload with the information of SMS messages the API should send
```

Request Example

```
[
  {
    "phone_number": "07791064781",
    "message": "Hello World",
    "device_id": 1
  },
  {
    "phone_number": "07791064782",
    "message": "Hello World",
    "device_id": 2
  }
]
```

I also check with postman but it is returning `"500 Internal Server Error"`

Can you please check and help me. Thanks.

Comment: are you still able to search the app on play store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read the docs on their site, and it appears that you might have forgotten to send the API key with the request. If you have the API key, you need to send it in an `Authorization` header.

```
Authorization: <the api key here>
```

Using Postman, you can set this header and retry.

Comment: Yes that worked. but where did you find this in documentation.?

Comment: I tracked the request on their demo page [here](https://smsgateway.me/dashboard/messages).

Comment: Could someone please post a complete example.  I am getting an error `"data":{"exception":"Invalid input"}`

Answer (score 2):

Get the Token from https://smsgateway.me. 
Login your account and click on settings then you will see the token.

```
public function sendMsgWithSmsGatewayApi($msg,$number,$deviceid)
    {
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => "https://smsgateway.me/api/v4/message/send",
          CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=>false,
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "[{\"phone_number\": \"$number\", \"message\": \"$msg\", \"device_id\": $deviceid}]",
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Cache-Control: no-cache",
            "Postman-Token: 0dfb5acc-f0ae-415b-a5d3-ca12a2dfdfd3",
            "authorization: Your-Token-here"
          ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        if ($err) {
          echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } else {
          echo $response;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the smsGateway.php last year and was able to implement the programmatically sms send, but on May 10, 2018 the app stop to work, I notice that the app was able to connect to smsGateway server but not able to retrieve the messages and the reason was because the program was not able to place the sms on the smsGateway server and looking deeper the error was that the device id was incorrect and it was not true, drilling down the problem I found that a new version was implemented from v3 to v4 and additional info was needed to submit form my php program to the smsGateway server, this is the Authorization key you can find it when you access the web page with your login and password. The challenge is how to integrate in the smsGateway.php I am still looking for that program with the changes to the new version but I was not able to find it yet.

May 16, 2018
smsgateway.me now published direction on how to integrate some software to programmatically send sms messages, the new challenge if you have a PHP 5.3 version you can expect to have some problems to integrate the new programs. By the way much more complicated than the v3.

There is also a note 'Please note we are still working on the documentation and will be introducing new SDKs soon!' which scares me a little bit. I am still working on the integration but, I am upgrading the PHP version to 5.6 and see if that is enough to eliminate the error messages.

After upgrading my php to 5.5 I was able to make smsgateway.me work, from 
https://github.com/smsgatewayme/client-php download the next set of programs files

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/autoload.php');
use SMSGatewayMe\Client\ApiClient;
use SMSGatewayMe\Client\Configuration;
use SMSGatewayMe\Client\Api\MessageApi;
use SMSGatewayMe\Client\Model\SendMessageRequest;

$clients = new SMSGatewayMe\Client\ClientProvider(
    "your key from website"
);
$sendMessageRequest = new SMSGatewayMe\Client\Model\SendMessageRequest
([
    'phoneNumber' => $HAMiLote['HASMSTel'], 
    'message' => $AXMessage, 'deviceId' => 100701
]);
$sentMessages =   
$clients->getMessageClient()->sendMessages([$sendMessageRequest]);

?><pre><?php print_r($sentMessages); ?></pre><?php
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this question. Would it be possible to edit your answer into a more succinct form (no need to explain all the background) and to tune it to more closely respond to the original question?

Comment: @juan Manuel I checked their website today, they have updated their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Since documentation on website is new and there is no example of sending sms to multiple phone numbers, I want to share this jQuery code that can be used to send sms using smsgateway.me .

```
var p = {
    "phone1": "9999999999",
    "phone2": "8888888888"
};

for (var key in p) {
    if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var phone_number = p[key];
        var message = "Test SMS";
        var device_id = 1;
        var obj = [{
            "phone_number": phone_number,
            "message": message,
            "device_id": device_id
        }];
        var mydata = JSON.stringify(obj);
        var settings = {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": "https://smsgateway.me/api/v4/message/send",
            "method": "POST",
            "headers": {
                "Authorization": "YOUR_API_KEY",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            "processData": false,
            data: mydata
        }
        $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
}
```

This jQuery code is working fine, but sometimes it sends multiple sms to any number in given js object. It may be due to `for` loop.